# Grub does not load on reboot

Tags: grub2, reboot

I just installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my Dell XPS 13 2015 (non Developer Edition). When I do a soft reboot, the computer does not start -- it displays the Dell logo and does not proceed further. (It it supposed to load grub afterwards.) The computer just hangs and I cannot find a way out of it (e.g., pressing F12 does not do anything).

This problem does not appear if I do a hard reboot.

I'm not sure why this is happening. I did modify the grub config file to change the resolution by following the directions in http://hgdev.co/optimize-ubuntu-interface-scaling-on-hidpi-displays/. But I'm not sure if this would cause the problem.

EDIT (10/29/15): It has been over a month since I attempted to use the restart feature. I just tried it today and it works fine! The issue must have been resolved by some software update.

Comment: try doing a **Sudo update-grub**

Comment: Does the hang on Dell logo happen everytime you reboot ? It happen to me too but in a very random way (every 30 reboot maybe).

Comment: @DavidCole I did try that many times, with no success.

Comment: @hg8 Yes, every time I reboot from Ubuntu. No hanging occurs if I reboot from Windows. (By the way, thanks for your guide -- it is super helpful!)